# Elasticsearch 2.1: Cannot install Marvel into Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4, elasticsearch-marvel

I am a newbie to the ES world and just trying to get my local environment set up.

I am using a Mac and I used Homebrew to install Elasticsearch and Kibana.
Now I want to add Marvel to Kibana but it fails with the following error:

```
user :/usr/local/opt/kibana/(master)$ bin/kibana plugin --install elasticsearch/marvel/latest
Installing marvel
Attempting to extract from https://download.elastic.co/elasticsearch/marvel/marvel-latest.tar.gz
Downloading 3843924 bytes....................
Extraction complete
Optimizing and caching browser bundles...
Plugin installation was unsuccessful due to error "Cannot find module 'bluebird'"
```

Unfortunately I haven't found any solution yet.
Maybe you guys have an idea how to solve this?

Cheers,
Stefan

Comment: Don't you need to use sudo to install it? E.g. "sudo bin/kibana plugin --install elasticsearch/marvel/latest"

Comment: Nope. Did not solve it:

`user: usr/local/opt/kibana/bin/(master)$ sudo kibana plugin --install elasticsearch/marvel/latest
Password:
Installing marvel
Attempting to extract from https://download.elastic.co/elasticsearch/marvel/marvel-latest.tar.gz
Downloading 3843924 bytes....................
Extraction complete
Optimizing and caching browser bundles...
Plugin installation was unsuccessful due to error "Cannot find module 'bluebird'"`

Comment: I also installed the node module "bluebird" globally: `npm install -g bluebird`but still not successfull

Comment: Hmm ok, what version of Kibana are you using?

Comment: I am using Version 4.3.1 Build 1.

Comment: Are you able to start & run the kibana server?

Comment: Yes, the Kibana server is up and running. I can access Kibana with the web browser.

Comment: My kibana will crash on a node error about bluebird; glad your works, though!

Comment: Same problem here. Looking for solutions too.

Comment: I solved it on my other machine (entire new setup) with the latest version of hombrew. I have now ES v 2.1.1 installed and all works (still) fine.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem and solved by installing kibana not from homebrew.

--> Check here: https://github.com/elastic/sense/issues/93