# Cannot install Marvel into Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-plugin

I have already looked at [Elasticsearch 2.1: Cannot install Marvel into Kibana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34651477/elasticsearch-2-1-cannot-install-marvel-into-kibana). That's not the same issue I have.

I am trying to install Marvel into Kibana. I have already installed Marvel and Kibana separately, but the guide says to use the following command to install Marvel into Kibana

`bin/kibana plugin --install elasticsearch/marvel.2.3.3`

I tried that and got the following:

```
Installing marvel.2.3.3
Attempting to transfer from https://download.elastic.co/elasticsearch/marvel.2.3.3/marvel.2.3.3-latest.tar.gz
Error: Client request error: connect ENETUNREACH 50.17.193.7:443
Plugin installation was unsuccessful due to error "Client request error: connect ENETUNREACH 50.17.193.7:443"
```

I thought it might be an issue with proxy settings so I tried using the same format I did to pass proxy settings when installing Marvel

```
bin/kibana plugin -DproxyHost=my.proxy.com -DproxyPort=80 --install elasticsearch/marvel/2.3.3
```

but that didn't work

```
error: unknown option `-D'
```

I have an ElasticSearch instance running and I am just trying to view it with the same UI like in the Getting Started video: https://info.elastic.co/2016-03-AB-Test-Getting-Started-ES_Video.html?aliId=43084931 but nothing is working.

I appreciate any advice. This is an extremely frustrating install and the documentation, videos, and support is beyond poor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elasticsearch 2.2 : Cant install marvel plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35180199/elasticsearch-2-2-cant-install-marvel-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

yes, this is a known issue

https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/5902

you can, however, circumvent this by first downloading the marvel zip file, and then installing it:

```
bin/kibana plugin -i marvel -u file:///tmp/marvel-latest.tar.gz
```